# 500px.com counting number of images in sets (or album)

Tags: php, html

I am having a tough time trying to figure out how to make a perfect calculation, 
and based on it adjust the div blocks that I am outputting to a template (HTML) with PHP code.

Here's a photo of what I am trying to do: 
[image]

However, I have no idea of exactly how to make this outputted so exact with the math and the calculation. If anyone knows how this is calculated by % percent and so one, feel free to share the mathematics on this, thanks!

Comment: what exactly are the input and output?

Comment: Those are a DIV and ul li with images tags. However, I am trying to figure out the math around this, I tend to have issues with smaller number of images, unfortunately, my code is huge with lots of if-statements, however, if there's a mathematical method, feel free to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, as it's not based on % widths but I'm sure it will put you on the right track.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/Rw4Yq/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:900px;
    height:220px;
}
div .image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#cdcdcd;
    display:inline-block;
}
div .image:nth-of-type(1) {
    min-width:205px;
    min-height:205px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
div .image:last-of-type {
    background:#0099FF;
    color:#fff;
}
```

You can easily adapt this to % widths to fit your needs but since you posted no code I had nothing to work with. Let me know if this solves your problem or not.

Comment: Cool, except that's not the issue, in addition, I am using ul li not divs, the container is a div. The thing is representing the data, e.g. 3 images, the 1st is larger (50%) the other two split 50%/2, but I want similar displaying even if the number of total images is 4 etc.

Comment: Well, I said you can adapt it to what you need. Change the width/height to percents and add implement it how you want. I'm not writing your site for you if you have shown no code.

Comment: @JohnSmith You can change the CSS to work on ul li in Divs. And you can change the widths to percentages. This is probably the only answer you will get as the question is worded poorly.